# How to delete through the VIEW?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Management Studio.

I have these tables:

```
alter table dob
(
    PIB int primary key,
    naziv nchar (10) not null,
    broj_racuna int
)

alter table ddob
(
    PIB int primary key,
    tel nchar (10) not null,
    MB int,
    adr nchar (10)
)
```

`PIB` is foreign key to table `dob`

I created a view `dd_all`:

```
SELECT D.PIB, D.naziv, D.broj_racuna, DD.telefon, DD.MB, DD.adresa
FROM  dbo.dob AS D 
INNER JOIN dbo.ddo AS DD ON D.PIB = DD.PIB
```

I need a trigger: when I delete something from the view, that trigger needs to delete it from `dob` and in `ddob`.

I tried with this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_1
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pib_delete int

    SELECT @pib_delete = PIB 
    FROM dob 
    WHERE dob.PIB = @pib_delete

    DELETE FROM dobavljac_sve 
    WHERE dobavljac_sve.PIB = @pib_delete

    DELETE FROM dobavljac 
    WHERE dobavljac.PIB = @pib_delete
END
```

Also:

```
declare @pib_delete int
select @pib_delete = PIB from dobavljac_sve where dobavljac_sve.PIB=@pib_delete

delete from dobavljac_sve where dobavljac_sve.PIB=@pib_delete
delete from dobavljac_detalji where dobavljac_detalji.PIB=@pib_delete
delete from dobavljac where dobavljac.PIB=@pib_delet
```

Comment: No one can really help when you post abbreviated DDL for 2 tables but a trigger that references 3 tables (2 of which are not included in your DDL). In addition, you suffer from a very common mistake. You assume one row is affected by a delete statement in your trigger - a false assumption. Go find discussions about triggers for beginners to understand that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger would need to look something like this:

```
begin
    delete d
        from ddob d
        where d.pib in (select dd.pib from deleted dd);

    delete d
        from dob d
        where d.pib in (select dd.pib from deleted dd);

end;
```

Comment: error message: view or function 'd' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

Comment: @BeginnerCoding . . . I fixed the table names.

Comment: again error: the row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(3 rows)   :/

Comment: dob is the parent table, so you need to delete "bottom up" if the FK is not set to cascade.

Comment: tried to swap places but gives error the row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(3 rows)

Comment: `ddob` should be the parent table. Note OP statement `PIB is foreign key to table dob`. There is nothing wrong with the trigger posted by Gordon. The error must be due to something else. @BeginnerCoding please show us your delete statement (please update your question with that delete statement)